# SwiftUI: Add animation to Picker without adding it to the values

Tags: swiftui, picker

I'm trying to animate the hiding/showing of a picker based on a toggle. If true or false, I would like the picker to `easeInOut`.

I've tried adding the `.animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0.5))` to the picker itself or the HStack the picker is in, but both add the animation to values inside the picker and when scrolling through the values the application to crashes.

```swift
        HStack {
            if showPicker {
                Picker(selection: $selected.value, label: Text(selected.type)) {
                    ForEach(digits, id: \.self) { d in
                        Text("\(d)")
                    }
                }
                .frame(width: 40)
            }
        }
        .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 2))
```

```swift
            if showPicker {
                Picker(selection: $selected.value, label: Text(selected.type)) {
                    ForEach(digits, id: \.self) { d in
                        Text("\(d)")
                    }
                }
                .frame(width: 40)
                .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0.5))
            }
```

Both options do animate the hiding/showing the picker, but it also animates scrolling through the values in the picker, which causes it to crash.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your first approach, putting animation on HStack. Never do that. According to the comments in the declaration file:

> Use this modifier on leaf views rather than container views. The
>   animation applies to all child views within this view; calling
>   `animation(_:)` on a container view can lead to unbounded scope.

I tried your second approach (filling the missing bits from your post), and it won't crash. Maybe you can update your question with a fully reproducible example.

***Changed animation to explicit, so other parameters are not affected:***

```swift
struct PickerStackOverflow: View {
    @State private var showPicker = true
    @State private var value: Int = 1

    let digits: [Int] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Selected \(value)")

            HStack {
                if showPicker {
                    Picker(selection: $value, label: Text("Label")) {
                        ForEach(digits, id: \.self) { d in
                            Text("\(d)")
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(width: 40)
                }
            }


            Button("Tap Me") {
                withAnimation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 2)) {
                    self.showPicker.toggle()
                }

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and still see the issue with the values in the picker, in this case 1-14, also getting the animation. If you comment out `.animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 2))` and run it again, you can see that it scrolls much smoother. If you scroll really fast, you still see all the numbers go by. With the animation modifier, if you scroll fast the values seem to disappear and the experience is kind of clunky.

Comment: Also, thanks for the information on about using an animation on a container.

Comment: I don't see what you comment. Are you in beta 5? Simulator? Device? Live Preview?

Comment: I updated the code so that it uses an explicit (instead of an implicit) animation. Since I cannot reproduce the problem, I don't know if that will fix it, but should.

Comment: Yes, explicit fixed it. Thank you! Just FYI for anyone else who might want to know, this is on beta 5 using the watch simulator.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Cheers.